Video player app for special needs child
I need a video/audio player app for a special needs child.
My only constraints are:

(preferably) for iOS (otherwise Android, or at most Windows x86 is fine, as long as there isn't any serious compromise on app functionality when operating Windows 11 soley from a touchscreen)
'Like watching TV': what I mean by this is that there mustn't be any way to 'scrub' from one part of the video to the other or 'skip' to the next video: all videos must play one after the other as if they were being watched on TV

Unfortunately using 'block interface' on VLC isn't effective, as:

The child knows the app is capable of doing more (besides the buttons remain visible, although non-functional) and is frustrated by this (when the whole point is to keep him calm by giving him something to watch from start to finish)
You can still jump from one video to another: this still allows repeating the same piece of video track again and again, which is no good!





Here's what I was thinking (unfortunately I haven't come to a clear decision yet!)
Local HTML server (Won't work on iOS, don't have the complete knowledge to set it al up)
Something like python -m http.server 8000, with a webpage that plays the videos it finds in a given folder one after the other (there mustn't be any controls to change the video playong of course though).
[unrelated to Software Recommendations] Ask someone to make this (I'm willing to offer bounties)
One of the most common ways of funding open-source projects involves the use of bounties; I've seen lots of sites offer this kind of thing, but I really don't know what the right place to ask this would be!
Of course I'm looking for something dead-simple and reliable: I was actually able to use the Python server from Android on localhost after running python -m http.server 8000 in Termux: just don't know how to design a site that meets my criteria!
Thank you so much for responding :>
